# td:4th child css not working in firefox & IE

Tags: html, css

I'v a table and I want to set length of the first column because it's a description.

Due to some reason the snippet below is not working in Firefox and IE. It is working fine in Chrome.

```
.tblFooter td:nth-child(3) {
    width:100px !important;
}

.tblFooter td:first-child {
    width: 450px !important;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: What is version of the browser?

Comment: Firefox Latest (53)version and IE 11

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yhvktvhj/ Tested with Chome, Internet Explorer 11 and Firefox 53 and all show identical results.

Comment: Please add your markup; without that it is impossible to tell why the CSS is not applied correctly.

Comment: @KiranMadhav, it's very strangely,  because this selector is supported by specific browsers. Is it possible to see your HTML snippet?

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yhvktvhj/7/ I checked with Chrome, IE and firefox i got identical results.